# Importing massive data on Python script

Tags: python, database, scripting

I'm trying to import a txt file as pandas on a daily basis. But I'm having issues because it has millions of data so it takes forever to load. I only need data from Jul 2021 onwards, but I have data since 2018. Anyone can help how I can load this faster with just data I need?

```
# load data that takes forever since it reads the millions of rows
basepath = r'\\SERVER\folder\file.TXT'
df = pd.read_csv(basepath, sep=';',  error_bad_lines=False, header=None)
df.head()
```

I'm not too sure about the chunk option, if it will get the right amount I need since data is added daily.

Comment: I assume that the CSV rows in the file are sorted by date or timestamp (ascending) and new data is just appended to the end of the file?

Comment: There is a date column yes, but the rows are pretty random and not sorted properly at least on the file I'm trying to read. I just need the rows where the date is after July 2021 out of the millions of rows.

Comment: If the requested rows can be randomly scattered over the file you have to read and process the whole file at least once. If you are sure that new data is only appended you can store necessary information about the already processed file (including its length) and continue the next day with only new data which was appended to the file.